# Convert return type to boolean with my-batis?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm currently using following mapping:

```
@Select ("select count(*) from something where id = 2344")
int userExists();
```

But i would like to have something like:

```
@Select ("select count(*) from something where id = 2344")
boolean userExists();
```

Can I convert 0 to false and everything > 0 to true ?

I'm using Oracle. Therefore I hope that my-batis provides some sort of return type mapping.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: It seems as if I can use a TypeHandler for that purpose. But so far I couldn't find any docs on how to annotate my interface with the TypeHandler I implemented.

Comment: What about simply querying `select count(*) > 0 ...` ? Haven't tried it, just a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can return boolean in Oracle, by using the case statement in Oracle:

```
@Select ("select case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end result from something where id = 2344")
boolean userExists();
```

Hope it is helpful to you.